# How to get the row and column number of a cell using a LibreOffice Basic function

Tags: libreoffice-calc, libreoffice-basic

I would like to write a Libreoffice-Basic function that takes into account the row and column of the cell where the function is placed.  I suppose my problem would be solved if I could define a function such as:

```
Function MyRowFun()
    MyRowFun = ?????
End Function
```

replicating the built-in function `ROW()`.  In other words, once I typed `"=MyRowFun()"` in any given cell, that cell would display the same as if I had typed `"=ROW()"`.

It would also be nice to be able to get the corresponding sheet name.

Thanks very much for any help, such as pointers to online manuals.

---

PS: After spending a lot of time searching, I have found many places explaining how to identify the cell under the selection, using `ThisComponent.CurrentSelection.AbsoluteName`, but I care about **the cell where the formula is placed**, rather than the currently selected cell.

Comment: Why are you making it difficult for yourself? You've searched a lot and you've probably seen "it's impossible" many times, haven't you? Yes, today the API does not provide such an opportunity (perhaps it will be implemented someday, I don’t think that soon). If you know that SHEET(), ROW() and COLUMN() without parameters can return sheet-row-column numbers, then just pass them as parameters when calling your UDF.

Comment: @JohnSUN, thanks for your comment.  Well, I guess I was unlucky or perhaps didn't use the correct search terms, but I haven't seen anyone mentioning that this is impossible so far.  Of course I had already thought of passing these things as parameters but I'm sure you'll agree that such a solution is not the most elegant.

Comment: Yes, I am also of the opinion that the end user needs to make things easier (for example, to free him from the need to pass three empty parameters sheet-column-row each time when calling my function). On the other hand, I agree with the developers who, when asked to provide information about the "caller", immediately ask "Why? What is the reason why your function wants to know about its position. What is your algorithm going to do with this information?" What would you answer them? Indeed, what are you going to write that requires not data values ​​(string,number,date) but cell position?

Comment: @JohnSUN, I guess your argument can also be used to support abolishing the built-in functions COLUMN() and ROW().

Comment: No, since TDF seeks to give users everything that Excel has (not in the VBA, but in the spreadsheet calculator), the whole range of functions. But they are in no hurry to open to us - you and me - access to some existing, but hidden opportunities. "Why do you need this? Do not produce essences beyond what is necessary." And so far no one has been able to explain to them what can be done knowing the cell address. (One convincing reason was "to get the color to assign the values ​​in this row to a certain category" met the objection "The color isn't information, this is a design tool")

Comment: I suppose there are many situations in which it is useful to know where you are, such as the following: how would  you write a user-defined function having the same effect as
`=IF([some-very-complicated-formula-involving-the-cell-above] <= 0, [this-value], IF([the-same-very-complicated-formula-envolving-the-cell-above] >= 1, [another-value], [still-another-value]))`?  
The point is, of course, to avoid computing the `[very-complicated-formula-involving-the-cell-above]` twice.

Comment: It would certainly be easy to do it by passing, as parameters, either the address or the value of the cell above, but do not forget that we are discussing ways to avoid passing any parameters, especially since the *location* is potentially available, as demonstrated by the very existence of the functions `ROW()` and `COLUMN()`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220676/discussion-between-johnsun-and-ruy).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone else who comes across this question, the solution is given in the first comment by @JohnSUN:

> If you know that SHEET(), ROW() and COLUMN() without parameters can return sheet-row-column numbers, then just pass them as parameters when calling your UDF.

The poster was hoping for a different type of solution but there isn't any other way.

Comment: That is certainly not the answer I was hoping for but it certainly ends my search!

Answer (score 0):

```
No SHEET(), ROW(), COLUMN()

Use Excel VBA Range. Just referring to itself. And without quotes.

C5: =UDF(Arg1;Agr2;C5)
________________________

Option VBASupport 1

Function UDF(Arg1, Arg2, Optional Caller)

    If Not IsMissing(Caller) Then

        sCallerName = Caller.CellRange.AbsoluteName

        Print sCallerName

    End If

End Function
```